# Replacing "from byte to byte", not "from character to character"

Tags: unicode, replace, visual-studio-code, character, byte

Motivated by [this issue](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/829) where the output of not(-yet)-Unicode-friendly ([maybe some day](https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?54750)) [chktex](http://www.nongnu.org/chktex/) is being used to [replace a part of the code](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/blob/master/src/providers/codeactions.ts#L60), I was wondering is there some way (similar to `WorkspaceEdit`'s method `replace` used in the referred code) to replace in "from byte to byte" fashion, instead of "from character to character"?

Retrieving whole specific line in a `string` would help as well, because then one could count bytes on its own.

Edit2. Is there something in vscode API that allows you to specify Range "from nth to mth byte", not "from nth to mth character"?